# Can any OnClickListener be added on Google's location permission dialog box?

Tags: android, android-studio, location

I am making a location based app in Android Studio which asks the user to grant permission to access the device's location when the user starts the app for the first time. Now I want to add an error message when the user clicks the DENY button in the Google's dialog box that asks the user to grant permission to access the location because my app won't work if the user denies to give permission to access the location. How can I do so?

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter you can get callback for denial of permission on that you can handle further logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:-

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
        for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            // user rejected the permission
                boolean showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( permission );
                if (! showRationale) {
                    // user also CHECKED "never ask again"   
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```